# During construction, pass this to RunWorkerAsync

Tags: c#, constructor, backgroundworker

I have this code

```
public class MyClass
{
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    /* ... */
    public MyClass()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += DoWhatever;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(this);
        /* Some other code */
    }
    internal static void DoWhatever(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
    {
        MyClass thingy = (MyClass)e.Argument; 
        /* ... */ 
    }
}
```

There I send the own instance to the worker. Could this cause any kind of thread-wise problems, or the code inside `DoWhatever` will wait until the instance is completely instantiated?

**Edit:** As clarified on the coments of the accepted answer, race-conditions may arise. This is not thread safe per-se, but if `RunWorkerAsync` is the last instruction then the constructor is thread safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an object reference is safe by itself. But indeed the constructor might not be completed when `DoWhatever` starts. There is no mechanism that magically waits for a constructor to finish until some other unrelated method can start. `BackgroundWorker` has no connection to whatever code is calling it. It cannot find out even if it wanted to.

Comment: I don't understand why "is safe by itself" but "the constructor might not be completed" mean.
What problems could arise?

Comment: A problem would be that DoWhatever runs before the ctor has completed. What is unclear about that?

Comment: What kind of error, exception, memory corruption, etc. would I face? That's my question

Comment: Whatever can happen when two pieces of code (neither of which I know) operate concurrently on the same piece of data. Nothing special here. Just the usual race conditions that happen with any race. Not specific to BackgroundWorker or to constructors.

Comment: So I'd be safe if `worker.RunWorkerAsync` is the last instruction on the constructor?

Comment: Yes because it is no longer possible that the two threads race on the same data. One of them (the ctor) does not access any more data at this point. A thread not accessing data clearly is free of races.